# How to use Maven dependencies in eclipse auto import

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a new maven project in eclipse and all maven stages work fine.
Problem comes when I write code.

I want classes in my dependencies to be available when I use organize imports.

On pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, eclipse does not use maven dependencies and I need to

- manually type imports: this shows errors due to java builder
- wait for maven build to compile

Can I not use eclipse java editor like I Used to with a simple java project which has some jars on classpath?

- If so, how?
- I hope there is a simple solution.
- I don't want to spend more spend time mavenizing then writing code.

Comment: Have you tried mvn eclipse:eclipse this should build the classpath for you

Comment: I have added this as an answer with more details

Comment: Which Eclipse edition do you use? Does it include m2e (Maven Integration for Eclipse)?

Comment: imo, the question and the answers below make no sense : all recent Eclipse include m2e, so as soon as you save a class, it's rebuild using Maven dependencies, and they are all available in Eclipse (you should even see them in a "Maven dependencies" section in the Java Project perspective).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Maven Eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) and tell it to download sources and javadocs for you or you can use [M2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/)(which automagically recognizes maven projects.)

> use mvn eclipse:eclipse thanks to  @Abdullah Shaikh

else

> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Organize Imports.(check
>   what your ctrl + shift +O do.?)

Comment: I am using it. Maven buold, compile, install works. What does not work is Ctrl _ Shift + O

Answer (score 0):

To convert a maven java project to support Eclipse, you can use below command to generate configuration files

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Run this command from the directory containing the pom.xml

In your case it will build classpath having all the dependencies mentioned in your pom

More details here [maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html)

Comment: It worked, but disturbed my other project types. I was using another project type. Eclipse has forgotten that behavior now.

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

But don't forget to change the directory to your maven project first (command cd)

Then reboot Eclipse

Than go to Eclipse Explorer - right click on your file with import errors - Source -
organize imports (or Ctrl-Shift-O)